# Facebook page accidently created by Like button with wrong URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

I've recently added a XFBML "recommend" button to my websites main page (index.html). The code in the body was like the following:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://my_page.com/index.html" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="230" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend" data-font="arial"></div>
```

The button worked for a while and I've got some likes too. Then I've started to fill the Open Graph Tag properties whereas I've made a mistake, I gave the root URL (http://my_page.com/) to the url property. I've also filled in the admin property, so in a few minutes FB automatically created an admisitration interface for my site and now I can see it in my profile as a FB site, but unfortunately I've lost all my likes because of the difference of the two URL.
Here is a code which was proven wrong for people with visual type:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://my_page.com/"/>
```

After I've noticed the loss of the likes, I've changed the OGT property to the one with index.html. The problem seems to be solved but I think it's would be much better if the root URL could be shown on Facebook walls when someone likes/shares it.
Can I merge the two URL-s for Facebook somehow?